# Mac Big Sur: Unable to load numpy_formathandler accelerator from OpenGL_accelerate

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl, glumpy

I keep getting an `Unable to load numpy_formathandler accelerator from OpenGL_accelerate` message when using OpenGL. From what I can tell, everything seems to be running fine, but message always pops up.

Here is a sample [script](https://www.labri.fr/perso/nrougier/python-opengl/code/chapter-03/quad-rotation.py) where it happens. It also happens with these two lines:

```
from glumpy import app, gloo, gl
window = app.Window()
```

Here is the output:

[image]

I am unsure if it is an issue but it is just annoying. I am running it with Big Sur using python 3.8.

Comment: Please include all the relevant code **in the question itself**

Comment: @BDL sorry about that. I have updated the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the sequence right as OpenGL.accerate is built.

```
### you can use pip

pip3 cache purge
pip3 uninstall PyOpenGL PyOpenGL.accelerate
pip3 install numpy # SciPy
pip3 install PyOpenGL PyOpenGL.accelerate

### you should be able to use that handler now
```